# Slicing Array of char in C++ (python to c++)

Tags: c++, python, arrays, string, char

I want to slice array of character in c++ or simply equivivalent code of python code given below.

```
s1 = ["A", "B", "C" , "D" , "E"]
s2 = s1[0:2] 

s2 ==> ["A","B"]
s1 ===> ["A", "B", "C" , "D" , "E"]
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I got my answer, i wanted to perform above task in c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects while working with strings and for retrieving some part of the string you can use [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

```
std::string s1("ABCDE");
std::string s2 = s1.substr(0, 2);
```

Comment: Slices don't refer to the same array, rather they refer to the same array *contents*.

Comment: @aaronman Wrong, in Python a slice is a new object (although Python `str`s, being immutable, use the same memory behind the scenes).